# Procuro indicações de livros para front-end

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou querendo saber se alguem tem uma indicação para livros voltado para o publico front-end.

Comment: Para javascript recomendo esse https://www.submarino.com.br/produto/126165214/livro-javascript-e-jquery-desenvolvimento-de-interfaces-web-interativas?opn=XMLGOOGLE&loja=1795809000110&epar=bp_pl_00_go_g35177&WT.srch=1&gclid=CjwKCAjwsJ3ZBRBJEiwAtuvtlP7sXLEvVBSdA2RAVfpwYxhJs4RrJzK1ytlMH_eGKKtIHN8nAw7reRoCJBIQAvD_BwE comprei na promoção e é um livro excepcional, bem grande ele. Para html e css recomendo esse https://www.submarino.com.br/produto/126167842/livro-html-e-css-projete-e-construa-webistes?DCSext.recom=RR_item_page.rr1-ClickCP&nm_origem=rec_item_page.rr1-ClickCP&nm_ranking_rec=1

Comment: O de html é do mesmo autor do outro livro e é da mesma série de desenvolvimento web, deve ser muito excepcional também

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Diego.Você deseja indicações de livros para iniciar no Front-End? Para se aperfeiçoar? Dei uma pesquisada no Google e encontrei esses. Espero que ajude.

1. https://www.casadocodigo.com.br/collections/livros-de-front-end
2. https://www.casadocodigo.com.br/collections/livros-de-front-end
3. https://www.casadocodigo.com.br/products/livro-guia-frontend
4. https://www.devmedia.com.br/principais-livros-front-end/32075
5. https://www.devmedia.com.br/forum/recomendacao-de-livros-front-end/585808